# Is there a way to force eject a react app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to eject the app using the `npm run eject` command which is mapped to `react-scripts eject`.

Is there a way to force this so that I don't see the prompt? Because when I run the command, it shows a prompt asking if you are sure.

Comment: By "forcing" you mean, ejecting without being prompted?

Comment: You could probably just use [`yes`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)).

Comment: Yes I don't want to see the prompt.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is there a way to not type it i.e. force it or automate it?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't seem to be supported, see [code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/ea7b37414aa887dfe7722bbc1c85b3291083053a/packages/react-scripts/scripts/eject.js#L40).

But like @jonrsharpe suggested you can try to force it with:

```
yes | npm run eject
```

Comment: When I typed this, the console keeps printing "y" for a long time before doing the ejection. Is this normal?